# How Show Column Result in Combobox vb.net SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have four columns in my table:

```
Item_name
Brand
Model
Price
```

I need to show results when I select an `Item_name`. When I select another oil, then show those result.

```
Private Sub ComboBox7_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox7.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    cmd.Connection = cn
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table_14 WHERE Item_Name='" & ComboBox7.Text & "'"
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    adapter.Fill(table)

    If table.Rows.Count() > 0 Then
        ComboBox2.Text = table.Rows(0)(1).ToString()
        ComboBox3.Text = table.Rows(0)(2).ToString()
        TextBox1.Text = table.Rows(0)(3).ToString()
    End If    
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: So, you're saying that when the user selects an `Item_Name` value in a `ComboBox`, you want to display the corresponding value from one or more of the other columns in one or more other controls, right?  If so, which columns and which controls?

Comment: yes i need  like i have 20 oil name items when the user click the oil then oil show their brand and model when the user select another oil then show the result their model brand

Comment: i have 4 column in my table (Item_Name, Model,Brand,Price)

Comment: Post the Complete Code here

Answer (score 1):

After populating your `DataTable`, you need to bind it to multiple controls - one for each column.  If `Item_Name` is the column that you want to select from then that is the column that gets bound to the `ComboBox`, while other columns would be bound to a `TextBox` or `Label`, e.g.

```vb
adapter1.Fill(table1)

itemNameComboBox.DisplayMember = "Item_Name"
itemNameComboBox.DataSource = table1

modelTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", table1, "Model")
```

Comment: i not understand post the complete code there is two parts of code one is i used for form load second i used for combobox where i use this code and what is text

Comment: the data will show in combobox but i need when i select oil they show their result

Comment: I think you donot understand ?